# How to automate flash with sikuli with selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, flash, selenium, sikuli

I am using flash website , that flash site contents text box and i want to enter value
  in that text box.
  I am using **sikuli-script.jar** with selenium webdriver with java.

Here is my code:

```
public void AISTest2()
    {
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("url of site");
    Screen s = new Screen();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(20000);            
        s.click(s.find("c:\\user.png"));
        s.type("mytextfieldvalue");
    } catch (FindFailed | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

when i execute this code following error comes:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 

 C:\Users\laxman\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplib\VisionProxy.dll: 
Can't find dependent libraries
```

Comment: Can you post a complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the path for sikuli libs folder to your environment PATH variable? If you are using a version earlier than 1.0.1 then you need to add SIKULI_HOME as well to the environmental variables.  See this link - https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/235169

Comment: Machine restart is also required sometimes. What version of Sikuli are you using? Can you post the paths you added to the PATH variable?

Comment: PATH=E:\laxman\Selenium webdriver java\libs; SIKULI_HOME=E:\laxman\Selenium webdriver java\libs;                         VERSION IS 1.0.1

Comment: Is libs the folder you have all the sikuli DLLs? Are these the latest files which come with version 1.0.1?

Comment: run your scripts from command line with -Dsikuli.Debug=3 option and paste the output logs